# Make firefox forget master password for session

Tags: firefox, passwords

I like to keep my PC (and Firefox) logged in for weeks.  When I start Firefox, it asks for my master password the first time I need a password I have saved.  After that, it always automatically fills in each password.

Can I reset it so that it will go back to prompting me?

Not every time, just the first time after the reset.

This way I can re-lock my session overnight.  I know I could simply shut down firefox and restart it but I don't want to do that as I often keep lots of windows open to remind me the next day what I was working on the night before.

Comment: What does switching to private browsing and back do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Master Password Timeout](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/master-password-timeout/) extension.

Comment: This extension is not working any more. It was probably too risky to use it, anyway. So I just [filed this as Mozilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1348274).

Answer (score 3):

You can switch between normal browsing and private browsing and then back.  All your tabs will still be there, but you'll have to re-enter your master password.

Comment: I like the look of the later answer suggesting Master Password Timeout.  I'm going to evaluate that before I accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the extension mentioned by `grawity` you can do it manually by going to Tools > Options > Advanced > Encryption > Security Devices, then select "Software Security Device" under "NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module". Now click on Log Out button.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password

Answer (score 0):

For current versions of firefox (2017)

one could set a bookbark to
about:preferences#advanced

and then click 
Certificates->Cryptography Modules->Internal PKCS #11 Module
->the Software Security Module->Log Out

As for wishfull thinking:

If an extension like "Master Password Timeout" should be so risky,
I would at least like to have an addon that presents me the dialog for
"Cryptography Modules" on one click :)